# Can't call table2excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

For my project I have to export a table to Excel.
But for some reason I can't call the function with a button press, but I can do it without the call.

```
<script>
    $("#studentTable").table2excel({
        exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
        name: "Worksheet Name",
        filename: "SomeFile.xls",
        preserveColors: true
    });
</script>
```

This way the table exports to Excel when the page loads and works fine.

```
<script>
    $("#exportBtn").click(function () {
        $("#studentTable").table2excel({
            exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
            name: "Worksheet Name",
            filename: "SomeFile.xls",
            preserveColors: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

But if I call the function with a button press, it doesn't work.
Can somebody please help.

I use the table2excel library from https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
```

This is the HTML page

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="studentTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Voornaam</th>
                        <th>Tussenvoegsel</th>
                        <th>Achternaam</th>
                        <th>Opleiding</th>
                        <th>Niveau</th>
                        <th>Jaar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>F</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>F</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>F</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">4</th>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>F</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">5</th>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>F</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="exportToExcel" id="exportBtn">
                Export to Excel
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you using a specific library? Like https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel If so please ensure that it is loaded properly. Check Console for any errors. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Since it works without the .click, I though it would be loaded properly. But now I see the console gives an error. $(...).table2excel is not a function. In the edit you can see the links i use

Comment: I do see the updates and I do not see any example Table data or the button you reference.

Comment: The extra code is in the question

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Only when I use the click one. $(...).table2excel is not a function

Comment: @Arthur070 this would suggest you are loading the library incorrectly. You may want to switch to `https://` in the source instead of allowing it to pick.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/m3oe05ky/

**HTML**

```
<table id="studentTable" class="table2excel" data-tableName="Student Table 1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Bart Simpson</td>
      <td>S001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lisa Simpson</td>
      <td>S002</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maggie Simpson</td>
      <td>S003</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="exportToExcel">Export to XLS</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".exportToExcel").click(function(event) {
    console.log("Exporting XLS");
    $("#studentTable").table2excel({
      exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
      name: $("#studentTable").data("tableName"),
      filename: "StudentTable.xls",
      preserveColors: false
    });
  });
});
```

Using:

- jQuery 3.4.1
- https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js

This appears to work as expected.

Comment: Same problemn again

Comment: studenten:91 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).table2excel is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (studenten:91)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @Arthur070 something is disrupting the loading of the library.

Comment: But how do i fix that. Because it only occurs when i use the button